# Fast access to 10000 arrays of double 200 x 200

Tags: c#

I will generate about 10000 arrays of 200 x 200 of sparsely populated double values (maximum 6 digits each). Each array should be identified by a code. The data is stored on the hard disk of a Windows machine. I want to have fast read/write access to any of the cells in this arrays, by row and cell indexes and to find the maximum/minimum of a row/column. Unless otherwise advised, I would create a separate file for each table in a directory and keep the data as comma separated values. The file name is the code for the table. Is there a better alternative to store and access this data? Would it be faster/safer to store it in a database? I would consider a free database or other free options as alternatives.

Comment: what has happened to you, user with gold medals asking such questions :(

Comment: There are things I know and things I don't know. Why should I be ashamed to ask other people who know some subjects better than myself?

Comment: No mate, i did not mean that, i favor to ask question without shame. upvoted!

Comment: If memory isn't a concern, I would use a `BinaryFormatter` to de/serialize a `Dictionary` where key is the identifying code and value is your 200x200 array to a file on disk. Once your app starts up, you can load it into memory and access will be as fast as you'll be able to get

Comment: Thanks Johan, I will play around with the BinaryFormatter and dictionary see what it can do. I haven't used yet the BinaryFormatter.

Comment: How is the data to be accessed - is it fast cell or always full row/column access? What requirements are there about such? Is space (ie. sparse data saving) a concern? Would a SQLite (eg.) database keyed (arr,row,col) be suitable?